# Parsing unique JSON

Tags: json, xml, vb.net, parsing, json.net

JSON:

```
"divisions": {
  "ocd-division/country:us": {
   "name": "United States",
   "officeIndices": [
    0,
    1
   ]
  },
  "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo": {
   "name": "Missouri",
   "officeIndices": [
    2,
    11,
    12
   ]
  },
  "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo/cd:6": {
   "name": "Missouri's 6th congressional district",
   "officeIndices": [
    3
   ]
  },
```

I'm trying to pull out `Missouri's 6th congressional district` from the above JSON. I can pull it out with the following code correctly:

```vb
Console.WriteLine(json.SelectToken("divisions").
        SelectToken("ocd-division/country:us/state:mo/cd:6").SelectToken("name").ToString)
```

This works just fine, but as you'll see `ocd-division/country:us/state:mo/cd:6` will not be the same for other states or even other parts of the state. I'm wondering why this isn't working to solve the problem...

```vb
Console.WriteLine(json.SelectToken("divisions").
        SelectToken("ocd-division/country:us").Next.Next.SelectToken("name").ToString)
```

I figured since all states will be in the `us` I could start there and then go two siblings forward to get to `Missouri's 6th congressional district`.

FULL JSON:

```vb
{
 "kind": "civicinfo#representativeInfoResponse",
 "normalizedInput": {
  "line1": "****** *** ***",
  "city": "******",
  "state": "**",
  "zip": "*****"
 },
 "divisions": {
  "ocd-division/country:us": {
   "name": "United States",
   "officeIndices": [
    0,
    1
   ]
  },
  "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo": {
   "name": "Missouri",
   "officeIndices": [
    2,
    4,
    5,
    8,
    9,
    10,
    11,
    12
   ]
  },
  "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo/cd:6": {
   "name": "Missouri's 6th congressional district",
   "officeIndices": [
    3
   ]
  },
  "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo/county:clay": {
   "name": "Clay County",
   "officeIndices": [
    13,
    14,
    15,
    16,
    17,
    18,
    19,
    20,
    21,
    22,
    23
   ]
  },
  "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo/place:kearney": {
   "name": "Kearney city"
  },
  "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo/sldl:38": {
   "name": "Missouri State House district 38",
   "officeIndices": [
    7
   ]
  },
  "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo/sldu:12": {
   "name": "Missouri State Senate district 12",
   "officeIndices": [
    6
   ]
  }
 },
 "offices": [
  {
   "name": "President of the United States",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us",
   "levels": [
    "country"
   ],
   "roles": [
    "headOfState",
    "headOfGovernment"
   ],
   "officialIndices": [
    0
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Vice-President of the United States",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us",
   "levels": [
    "country"
   ],
   "roles": [
    "deputyHeadOfGovernment"
   ],
   "officialIndices": [
    1
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "United States Senate",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo",
   "levels": [
    "country"
   ],
   "roles": [
    "legislatorUpperBody"
   ],
   "officialIndices": [
    2,
    3
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "United States House of Representatives MO-06",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo/cd:6",
   "levels": [
    "country"
   ],
   "roles": [
    "legislatorLowerBody"
   ],
   "officialIndices": [
    4
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Governor",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo",
   "levels": [
    "administrativeArea1"
   ],
   "roles": [
    "headOfGovernment"
   ],
   "officialIndices": [
    5
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Lieutenant Governor",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo",
   "levels": [
    "administrativeArea1"
   ],
   "roles": [
    "deputyHeadOfGovernment"
   ],
   "officialIndices": [
    6
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "MO State Senate District 12",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo/sldu:12",
   "levels": [
    "administrativeArea1"
   ],
   "roles": [
    "legislatorUpperBody"
   ],
   "officialIndices": [
    7
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "MO State House District 38",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo/sldl:38",
   "levels": [
    "administrativeArea1"
   ],
   "roles": [
    "legislatorLowerBody"
   ],
   "officialIndices": [
    8
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "State Supreme Court Judge",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo",
   "officialIndices": [
    9,
    10,
    11,
    12,
    13,
    14,
    15
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "State Treasurer",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo",
   "officialIndices": [
    16
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Attorney General",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo",
   "officialIndices": [
    17
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "State Auditor",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo",
   "officialIndices": [
    18
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Secretary of State",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo",
   "officialIndices": [
    19
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Assessor",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo/county:clay",
   "officialIndices": [
    20
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Treasurer",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo/county:clay",
   "officialIndices": [
    21
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Circuit Clerk",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo/county:clay",
   "officialIndices": [
    22
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Auditor",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo/county:clay",
   "officialIndices": [
    23
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "County Commissioner Chairman",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo/county:clay",
   "officialIndices": [
    24
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "County Clerk",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo/county:clay",
   "officialIndices": [
    25
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Collector",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo/county:clay",
   "officialIndices": [
    26
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Prosecuting Attorney",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo/county:clay",
   "officialIndices": [
    27
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Sheriff",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo/county:clay",
   "officialIndices": [
    28
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Recorder",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo/county:clay",
   "officialIndices": [
    29
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Public Administrator",
   "divisionId": "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo/county:clay",
   "officialIndices": [
    30
   ]
  }
 ],
 "officials": [
  {
   "name": "Donald J. Trump",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "The White House",
     "line2": "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW",
     "city": "Washington",
     "state": "DC",
     "zip": "20500"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican Party",
   "phones": [
    "(202) 456-1111"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "http://www.whitehouse.gov/"
   ],
   "photoUrl": "https://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/whitehouse.gov/files/images/45/PE%20Color.jpg",
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "GooglePlus",
     "id": "+whitehouse"
    },
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "whitehouse"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "potus"
    },
    {
     "type": "YouTube",
     "id": "whitehouse"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Mike Pence",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "The White House",
     "line2": "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW",
     "city": "Washington",
     "state": "DC",
     "zip": "20500"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican Party",
   "phones": [
    "(202) 456-1111"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "http://www.whitehouse.gov/"
   ],
   "photoUrl": "https://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/whitehouse.gov/files/images/45/VPE%20Color.jpg",
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "GooglePlus",
     "id": "+whitehouse"
    },
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "whitehouse"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "VP"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Roy Blunt",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "260 Russell Senate Office Building",
     "city": "Washington",
     "state": "DC",
     "zip": "20510"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican Party",
   "phones": [
    "(202) 224-5721"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "http://www.blunt.senate.gov/"
   ],
   "photoUrl": "http://bioguide.congress.gov/bioguide/photo/B/B000575.jpg",
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "SenatorBlunt"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "RoyBlunt"
    },
    {
     "type": "YouTube",
     "id": "SenatorBlunt"
    },
    {
     "type": "YouTube",
     "id": "BluntforSenate2010"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Josh Hawley",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "B40A Dirksen Senate Office Building",
     "city": "Washington",
     "state": "DC",
     "zip": "20510"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican Party",
   "phones": [
    "(202) 224-6154"
   ],
   "emails": [
    "senator@hawley.senate.gov"
   ],
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "SenHawleyPress"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Sam Graves",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "1135 Longworth House Office Building",
     "city": "Washington",
     "state": "DC",
     "zip": "20515"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican Party",
   "phones": [
    "(202) 225-7041"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "http://graves.house.gov/"
   ],
   "photoUrl": "https://graves.house.gov/sites/graves.house.gov/files/documents/Rep_Graves_Photo.JPG",
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Facebook",
     "id": "118514606128"
    },
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "repsamgraves"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Mike Parson",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "P.O. Box 720",
     "city": "Jefferson City",
     "state": "MO",
     "zip": "65102"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican Party",
   "phones": [
    "(573) 751-3222"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "https://governor.mo.gov/"
   ],
   "photoUrl": "https://ltgov.mo.gov/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Parson-headshot.jpg",
   "emails": [
    "ltgovinfo@ltgov.mo.gov"
   ],
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "GovParsonMO"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Mike Kehoe",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "201 W. Capital Avenue",
     "line2": "Room 224",
     "city": "Jefferson City",
     "state": "MO",
     "zip": "65101"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican Party",
   "phones": [
    "(573) 751-4727"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "https://ltgov.mo.gov/"
   ],
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "LtGovMikeKehoe"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Dan Hegeman",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "201 W CAPITOL AVE RM 332",
     "line2": "JEFFERSON CTY",
     "city": "",
     "state": "MO",
     "zip": "65101"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican Party",
   "phones": [
    "(573) 751-1415"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "http://www.senate.mo.gov/mem12"
   ],
   "photoUrl": "http://www.senate.mo.gov/17web/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Hegeman-200x300.jpg",
   "emails": [
    "Dan.Hegeman@senate.mo.gov"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Doug Richey",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "201 W CAPITOL AVE 116 A-1",
     "line2": "JEFFERSON CTY",
     "city": "",
     "state": "MO",
     "zip": "65101"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican Party",
   "phones": [
    "(573) 751-2238"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "http://www.house.mo.gov/MemberDetails.aspx?district=38"
   ],
   "emails": [
    "Doug.Richey@house.mo.gov"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Patricia Breckenridge",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "Missouri Supreme Court",
     "line2": "207 West High Street,",
     "city": "Jefferson City",
     "state": "MO",
     "zip": "65101"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Nonpartisan",
   "phones": [
    "(573) 751-4144"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "https://www.courts.mo.gov/page.jsp?id=499"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "W. Brent Powell",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "Missouri Supreme Court",
     "line2": "207 West High Street,",
     "city": "Jefferson City",
     "state": "MO",
     "zip": "65101"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Nonpartisan",
   "phones": [
    "(573) 751-4144"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "https://www.courts.mo.gov/page.jsp?id=113629"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Mary R. Russell",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "Missouri Supreme Court",
     "line2": "207 West High Street,",
     "city": "Jefferson City",
     "state": "MO",
     "zip": "65101"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Nonpartisan",
   "phones": [
    "(573) 751-4144"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "https://www.courts.mo.gov/page.jsp?id=203"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "George W. Draper, III",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "Missouri Supreme Court",
     "line2": "207 West High Street,",
     "city": "Jefferson City",
     "state": "MO",
     "zip": "65101"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Nonpartisan",
   "phones": [
    "(573) 751-4144"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "https://www.courts.mo.gov/page.jsp?id=50536"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Paul C. Wilson",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "Missouri Supreme Court",
     "line2": "207 West High Street,",
     "city": "Jefferson City",
     "state": "MO",
     "zip": "65101"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Nonpartisan",
   "phones": [
    "(573) 751-4144"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "https://www.courts.mo.gov/page.jsp?id=59001"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Zel M. Fischer",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "Missouri Supreme Court",
     "line2": "207 West High Street,",
     "city": "Jefferson City",
     "state": "MO",
     "zip": "65101"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Nonpartisan",
   "phones": [
    "(573) 751-4144"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "https://www.courts.mo.gov/page.jsp?id=27084"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Laura Denvir Stith",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "Missouri Supreme Court",
     "line2": "207 West High Street,",
     "city": "Jefferson City",
     "state": "MO",
     "zip": "65101"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Nonpartisan",
   "phones": [
    "(573) 751-4144"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "https://www.courts.mo.gov/page.jsp?id=183"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Scott Fitzpatrick",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "P.O. Box 210",
     "city": "Jefferson City",
     "state": "MO",
     "zip": "65102"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican Party",
   "phones": [
    "(573) 751-8533"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "https://www.treasurer.mo.gov/"
   ],
   "emails": [
    "info@treasurer.mo.gov"
   ],
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "MOTreasurer"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Eric Schmitt",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "207 W. High Street",
     "line2": "P.O. Box 899",
     "city": "Jefferson City",
     "state": "MO",
     "zip": "65102"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican Party",
   "phones": [
    "(573) 751-3321"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "https://www.ago.mo.gov/"
   ],
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "AGEricSchmitt"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Nicole Galloway",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "P.O. Box 869",
     "city": "Jefferson City",
     "state": "MO",
     "zip": "65102"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Democratic Party",
   "phones": [
    "(800) 347-8597"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "https://auditor.mo.gov/"
   ],
   "emails": [
    "moaudit@auditor.mo.gov"
   ],
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "AuditorGalloway"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "John (Jay) Ashcroft",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "600 West Main Street,",
     "city": "Jefferson City",
     "state": "MO",
     "zip": "65101"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican Party",
   "phones": [
    "(573) 751-4936"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "https://www.sos.mo.gov/"
   ],
   "emails": [
    "info@sos.mo.gov"
   ],
   "channels": [
    {
     "type": "Twitter",
     "id": "MissouriSOS"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Cathy Rinehart",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "1 Courthouse Square",
     "city": "Liberty",
     "state": "MO",
     "zip": "64068"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Democratic Party",
   "phones": [
    "(816) 407-3500"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "https://www.claycountymo.gov/departments/assessor"
   ],
   "emails": [
    "assessor@claycountymo.gov"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Ted Graves",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "1 Courthouse Square",
     "city": "Liberty",
     "state": "MO",
     "zip": "64068"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican Party",
   "phones": [
    "(816) 407-3540"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "https://www.claycountymo.gov/departments/treasurer"
   ],
   "emails": [
    "treasurer@claycountymo.gov"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Lee Bucksath",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "11 South Water Street",
     "city": "Liberty",
     "state": "MO",
     "zip": "64068"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Unknown",
   "phones": [
    "(816) 407-3900"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "http://www.circuit7.net/circuitclerk/"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Victor S. Hurlbert",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "1 Courthouse Square",
     "city": "Liberty",
     "state": "MO",
     "zip": "64068"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican Party",
   "phones": [
    "(816) 407-3590"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "https://www.claycountymo.gov/departments/auditor"
   ],
   "emails": [
    "auditor@claycountymo.gov"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Jerry Nolte",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "1 Courthouse Square",
     "city": "Liberty",
     "state": "MO",
     "zip": "64068"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican Party",
   "phones": [
    "(816) 407-3600"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "https://www.claycountymo.gov/departments/boards-commissions"
   ],
   "emails": [
    "commission@claycountymo.gov"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Megan Thompson",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "1 Courthouse Square",
     "city": "Liberty",
     "state": "MO",
     "zip": "64068"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican Party",
   "phones": [
    "(816) 407-3570"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "https://www.claycountymo.gov/departments/county-clerk"
   ],
   "emails": [
    "clerk@claycountymo.gov"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Lydia McEvoy",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "1 Courthouse Square",
     "city": "Liberty",
     "state": "MO",
     "zip": "64068"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican Party",
   "phones": [
    "(816) 407-3200"
   ],
   "emails": [
    "collector@claycountymo.gov"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Dan White",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "11 S Water Street",
     "city": "Liberty",
     "state": "MO",
     "zip": "64068"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Democratic Party",
   "phones": [
    "(816) 736-8300"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "http://www.circuit7.net/prosatty/"
   ],
   "emails": [
    "jim_roberts@claycopa.com"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Paul Vescovo, III",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "12 S. Water St.",
     "city": "Liberty",
     "state": "MO",
     "zip": "64068"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican Party",
   "phones": [
    "(816) 407-3750"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "http://www.claymosheriff.org/index.html"
   ],
   "emails": [
    "sheriff@sheriffclayco.com"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Katee Porter",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "1 Courthouse Square",
     "city": "Liberty",
     "state": "MO",
     "zip": "64068"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican Party",
   "phones": [
    "(816) 407-3550"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "https://www.claycountymo.gov/departments/recorder-deeds"
   ],
   "emails": [
    "recorder@claycountymo.gov"
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Sarah Mills",
   "address": [
    {
     "line1": "11 S Water Street",
     "city": "Liberty",
     "state": "MO",
     "zip": "64068"
    }
   ],
   "party": "Republican Party",
   "phones": [
    "(816) 407-3250"
   ],
   "urls": [
    "http://www.claycomopa.com/"
   ],
   "emails": [
    "ccadmin@claycountymo.gov"
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Use the class named **`CivicInfo`**, add it to your Project.

If you're reading from a File or Stream, open the File or Stream (sample provided) or directly pass the JSON Object (the string) to the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` method:
If you're reading from an existing Stream (i.e., from the Web), use only the `StreamReader`.

```vb
Dim civicInfo As CivicInfo.RootObject = Nothing
Using stream As Stream = New FileStream("[File Name]", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
    Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(stream)
        Dim JSONObject As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
        civicInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of CivicInfo.RootObject)(JSONObject)
    End Using
End Using
```

Now you have a complete class structure representing your JSON.
You can get/set a property value as usual.

For example, extract the info on an Official using a partial Name:

```vb
Dim official = civicInfo.officials.FirstOrDefault(Function(off) off.Name.Contains("Fitzpatrick"))
```

Will return:

```vb
official.Name = "Scott Fitzpatrick"
official.Party = "Republican Party"
'(...)
```

Extract all the Democratic Party's Officials:

```vb
Dim demOfficials = civicInfo.officials.Where(Function(ofs) ofs.Party.Contains("Democratic"))
```

Will return an IEnumerable of 3 **`Official`** classes.

Extract the District:

```vb
Dim district = civicInfo.divisions.FirstOrDefault(Function(dict) dict.Key.Contains("/cd")).Value
```

Will return:

```vb
district.Name = "Missouri's 6th congressional district"
district.OfficeIndices = [List(Of Long)] { 3 }
```

Complete `CivicInfo` class:

```vb
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class CivicInfo
    Partial Public Class RootObject
        Public Property kind As String
        Public Property normalizedInput As NormalizedInput
        Public Property divisions As Dictionary(Of String, Division)
        Public Property offices As List(Of Office)
        Public Property officials As List(Of Official)
    End Class

    Partial Public Class Division
        <JsonProperty("name")>
        Public Property Name As String

        <JsonProperty("officeIndices")>
        Public Property OfficeIndices As List(Of Long)
    End Class

    Partial Public Class NormalizedInput
        Public Property Line1 As String
        Public Property Line2 As String
        Public Property City As String
        Public Property State As String
        Public Property Zip As String
    End Class

    Partial Public Class Office
        Public Property Name As String
        Public Property DivisionId As String
        Public Property Levels As List(Of String)
        Public Property Roles As List(Of String)
        Public Property OfficialIndices As List(Of Long)
    End Class

    Partial Public Class Official
        Public Property Name As String
        Public Property Address As List(Of NormalizedInput)
        Public Property Party As String
        Public Property Phones As List(Of String)
        Public Property Urls As List(Of Uri)
        Public Property PhotoUrl As Uri
        Public Property Channels As List(Of Channel)
        Public Property Emails As List(Of String)
    End Class

    Partial Public Class Channel
        Public Property Type As String
        Public Property Id As String
    End Class
End Class
```

Comment: Ohhh okay I think I see where I was going wrong, i was using the "Paste JSON" method in visual studios and I think that's what was messing me up. Works perfect! Thank you so much for your time!!

Comment: Ah, yes, when the JSON has some *complexity*, you can't trust any automatic converter. You'll have to use your hands :)